# New to Javascript & JQuery: Why will my AJAX anchors work only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I come from a C, C++, and Java programming background, now getting my feet wet with Javascript and JQuery for a personal project I'm working on.

I've created the main page for my project which is supposed to be a "login/create account/send password reset code/resend activation code" page. The elements of interest are:

- a div containing the current form
- a div containing the anchors to the other forms
- a div containing the two previous divs

The page originally starts out with the login form and its associated anchor div. Clicking one of the anchors in the anchor div (the "create account" anchor for example), calls the JQuery replaceWith() method to replace the current form div and the anchor div with the requested form div and its associated anchor div.

The code works... but only once for each time an anchor is clicked. Why is this? I placed the JQuery elements in variables before they're used so they're available even though they've been "removed" from the DOM, or so I thought. Can anyone help shed some light?

Here is the code (".formAndLinksDivs" is a class given to all of the divs which enclose a form and an anchor div, and "#content" is the main div of the page which encloses those types of divs):

```
var varCreateAccountFormAndLinksDiv;
var varLoginFormAndLinksDiv;
var varSendAnotherActivationCodeFormAndLinksDiv;
var varSendResetCodeFormAndLinksDiv;

$(function() {

    varCreateAccountFormAndLinksDiv = $("#createAccountFormAndLinksDiv");
    varLoginFormAndLinksDiv = $("#loginFormAndLinksDiv");
    varSendAnotherActivationCodeFormAndLinksDiv = $('#sendAnotherActivationCodeFormAndLinksDiv');
    varSendResetCodeFormAndLinksDiv = $('#sendResetCodeFormAndLinksDiv');

    $(".ajaxLinkCreateAccount").click(function() {
        $('#content > .formAndLinksDivs').replaceWith(varCreateAccountFormAndLinksDiv);
        $(varCreateAccountFormAndLinksDiv).effect('slide', {direction: "down", distance: $(this).height()});
    });

    $(".ajaxLinkLogin").click(function() {
        $('#content > .formAndLinksDivs').replaceWith(varLoginFormAndLinksDiv);
        $(varLoginFormAndLinksDiv).effect('slide', {direction: "down", distance: $(this).height()});
    });

    $(".ajaxLinkSendAnotherActivationCode").click(function() {
        $('#content > .formAndLinksDivs').replaceWith(varSendAnotherActivationCodeFormAndLinksDiv);
        $(varSendAnotherActivationCodeFormAndLinksDiv).effect('slide', {direction: "down", distance: $(this).height()});
    });

    $(".ajaxLinkSendResetCode").click(function() {
        $('#content > .formAndLinksDivs').replaceWith(varSendResetCodeFormAndLinksDiv);
        $(varSendResetCodeFormAndLinksDiv).effect('slide', {direction: "down", distance: $(this).height()});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.click()` is registered when the DOM loads. `.live('click', ...)` is bound to an arbitrary element, which is what you need when you are creating elements with jQuery and attaching events to them.

So I'd change these types of function definitions:

```
$(".ajaxLinkSendResetCode").click(function()
```

Into these:

```
$(".ajaxLinkSendResetCode").live('click', function()
```

Comment: Um, `click` is a shortcut for `bind('click'`.  Your examples are identical.  Do you mean `live`?

Answer (score 1):

If the elements you are attaching your handlers to are being replaced with new elements, the basic event handler attach methods get "overwritten" when their elements get replaced. To combat this, use [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to attach the events. This will make sure the handlers apply to any elements matching your selector, even as elements are added/removed.

Answer (score 1):

The click event is bound to the object you removed, not to the new object.

Take a look at the [Live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) handler instead of using the .click() binding.